# Access created pdf file on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I can create pdf file but I can't find the created file on iPhone device. When I run it on simulator it's possible to find directory where it saved. Where do I have to save it to preview on iPhone?

This is the code for creating pdf file:

```
func createPDF() {
let html = "<b>Hello <i>World!</i></b> <p>Generate PDF file from HTML in Swift</p>"
let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

// 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer

let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

// 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
let printable = CGRectInset(page, 0, 0)

render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

// 4. Create PDF context and draw

let pdfData = NSMutableData()
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil)

for i in 1...render.numberOfPages() {

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
    render.drawPageAtIndex(i - 1, inRect: bounds)
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

// 5. Save PDF file

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

pdfData.writeToFile("\(documentsPath)/file.pdf", atomically: true)
}
```

Comment: print (\(documentsPath))

Comment: @Vinodh I can see this folder on Mac but the problem is I can't see on iPhone. I made UIAlertController and I printed documentsPath on it. Then I see where it saved on iPhone but still I can't access there. Hope you got I mean

Comment: use iExplorer application to view or access Document directory in iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preview it, you need to either renter in in your own view in your own app, or otherwise share that pdf to other app, like share it via email, whatsapp, pages app or any other app.

For sharing that pdf, you can use `UIActivityViewController`.

Here, I am adding code for using the same with objective-c, you can convert it into swift as it is needed.

```
NSString *pdfFilePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFilePath];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"My PDF File", URL]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^{
                 }];
```

Swift 3.0 code will be like:

```
    let pdfFilePath = "path to file.pdf";
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: pdfFilePath);
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["My Pdf File",url], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Comment: I'm new on ios programming now. Can you please help me to convert it into Swift. Then I can try.

Comment: which swift version you are using?

Comment: I use Swift 3. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] + "/file.pdf"
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath))
    webView.loadRequest(myRequest)
```

You can display the contents of the pdf in UIWebView.